# How to search the correponding JSP file of any web page/HTML page?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I have  a web application . When i right click on any html/webpage inside my browser , for some pages it shows the excaxt jsp page like
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/vustomer.jsp while for some pages it shows action class instead of jsp page like 
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/TellerAction.do?actionCode=3&page=controlPanel. I am not getting what is reason behind these two different
behaviour? i mean why it does show jsp file name for some page but not for others?

Comment: By the way, title of question correlates poorly with the text of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess because HTML code of page sometimes has `<a href='...jsp'>...</a>` and other times it has `<a href='...do'>...</a>`.

Your best bet to find out why is to ask author of code :)

Usually, `.do` URLs are served by servlets, not jsp.